# Print other click data in Material Select

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to paint in the select the same item selected but with its abbreviated data. In this only *option*.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="articleDataChange($event)" formControlName="article">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let i of articlesList" [value]="ref">Art: {{ i.option }} Desc:
        {{i.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [`mat-select-trigger`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label) as follows (replace `...` by the desired property of the selected artice):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="articleDataChange($event)" formControlName="article">
    <mat-select-trigger>{{ ... }}</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let i of articlesList" [value]="ref">Art: {{ i.option }} Desc:
        {{i.value}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```